# R creating a list using variable columns from df

Tags: r

I'm looking for the cleanest way to implement the following.

```
vars <- c("f1", "f2", "f3")
list(data$f1, data$f2, data$f3)
```

Where instead I make the list by using each string in vars instead of hardcoding the `data$f1, data$f2, ...`

It can be solved easily using a for loop to create the list but is there a one-liner/lapply way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` is a dataframe, then it's already a list.  You can do this:

```
data[,vars]
```

Or you can make it a simple list:

```
c(data[,vars])
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that c(df) yields a list, that's very useful to know.